# Connect to multiple mysql database in a single Resource

Tags: mysql, tomcat, rds

I am using RDS and have one master database which I write to and two read replication databases

I am using tomcat jdbc and I connect to the database via

Now I need to connect to the second read replication database but don't want to define a third Resource, I want a single resource for reading which connects to the two databases

Below is the current config (context.xml in web app)

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            name="jdbc/iomdb"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://mydbinstance.blah:3306/mydb?user=user&amp;password=p"
            maxActive="4"/>


<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            name="jdbc/iomdbread"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://readreplicaiom.ff.com:3306/mydb?user=user&amp;password=p"
            maxActive="4"/>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) to broker the requests to the two read instances invisibly to the application?

Comment: Warning
MySQL Proxy is currently an Alpha release and should not be used within production environments. So not a option unfortunately

Comment: I can't think of another way to solve the OP's problem. Can you?